# Heating wire filament with low voltage high current?

Tags: wire, heat, watts

Is it possible to heat  nichrome  wire  with 0.5V 20A?

what is the different between heat produced by 0.5v 20A (10watt) and 10v 1a (10watt) ?

Comment: Depends on how thick and long the wire is.

Comment: i am already have two wire..i want to know  the different between heat produced by 0.5v 20A (10watt) and 10v 1a (10watt) ?

Comment: Once you have the wire (R) and it's length selected you are stuck. For a given power (P), there is only one I,V combination that will satisfy V = IR and P = IV simultaneously.

Answer (score 3):

Nichrome has a certain resistivity (which varies with temperature and exact alloy). To use a lower voltage means you have to have lower resistance, all other things being equal. Resistance of the wire is:

\$\rho L/A\$ where \$\rho\$ is the resistivity of Nichrome, L is the length of the wire and A is the cross-sectional area of the wire (\$\pi r^2\$ if the wire is round).

In your two examples, the resistance is 25m\$\Omega\$ or 10\$\Omega\$, a 1:400 ratio.

If the wire is fixed length (for example for a wire foam cutter) then the lower voltage wire must be \$\sqrt{400}\$ times larger diameter or 20:1.

The heat loss will be a bit different with the different sizes of wire. There is a good set of tables on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nichrome).

Comment: Additionally, the lower resistance wire will have a lower efficiency considering any resistance in other components (source internal impedance, wiring to source, etc.).